# Interaction Studio Studio Article Recommendation

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations, interaction-studio

Our company has a website which is related to food. We want to use interaction studio einstein recipe to recommend food recipes based on the product the user is interested in. We are storing all the product information in the Product catalogue and all the food recipes in the article catalogue in Interaction Studio. We know Article and Product are the built-in catalogue object we cannot directly set up a relationship between them.  Here we used the related catalogue object "Material" which is common for Product/Article. Is there a way to configure the Einstein recipe so that when the product is selected we should be able to recommend food recipes from the Article catalogue based on the same product? We want to send an email with these recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this in several ways, with slightly different configurations and results.

For article recommendations on product pages only, you could set an Inclusion in the Recipe so that only Articles with the Material being viewed are returned.

A different way would be to include Boosters in your Recipe: Say a specific visitor develops an affinity towards Material "A" because of their product browsing. You can leverage that in a Recipe by recommending articles boosted with the Material affinity. You can play with the Weight and Threshold to fine-tune your recommendations.

Lastly, you could leverage the Compatibility criteria in Exclusions/Inclusions with your Material records: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_pers_einstein_recipe_exclusion_inclusion.htm&type=5

This would require pre-configuration of what Materials are compatible.

Good luck!